# File ownership preservation with .tgz

Tags: permissions, tar, archive, unix-philosophy

Back with another probably very very basic UNIX question.

I understand the premise of Tape Archive Zips (`.tgz`) is that they preserve uid, gid, permissions...

However, it seems that this isn't portable. For example, what if the user `john` makes a .tgz on one UNIX machine and unzips on a machine without that user, or with a user with the same name but different UID.

How does this work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Really old `tar` formats only store numerical user and group identifiers, and so they have the problem you describe.

However beginning with the POSIX standard from 1988, `tar` formats such as [the Unix standard `tar` format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#UStar_format) or [`pax`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#POSIX.1-2001/pax) also store the username and group name, so they can preserve ownership by name. Given a tarball containing a file owned by uid 1234, with username `john`, `tar` will look for a user named `john`, and extract the file with that ownership if possible (potentially with a uid that’s not 1234), falling back to uid 1234 if there is no such user.

None of this is perfect, which is why `tar` doesn’t restore ownership unless run as root (aside from the fact that it needs to be root to change ownership anyway); by default files are extracted with the ownership of the running user.

Comment: See also the `--numeric-owner`, `--owner`, `--uname`, `--uid`, etc. of some `tar` implementations.

Comment: Great answer, thank you!

Comment: *tar doesn’t restore permissions* Did you mean "ownership"?

Comment: Indeed, thanks @chrylis, I’ve fixed that.

Comment: This is important too: **"aside from the fact that it needs to be root to change ownership anyway"**. An unprivileged process cannot give away files to a different user, even if it knows who it wants to give them to.